# CKAN API ISSUE with organisation_show

Tags: api, ckan

When i call my ckan api with this endpoint : 
192.168.56.20/api/action/organization_show?id=org
I get just the information about the oganisation but no the list of my datasets.

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the parameter `include_datasets=True`

RTFM
http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/api/index.html#ckan.logic.action.get.organization_show

BTW there are advantages to use package_search. It doesn't have the 1000 dataset limit for one.

Comment: The API docs aren't clear on how you can call package_search with an organisation filter. They suggest an fq option for a filter, but I can't find any hints on how to construct the fq string.